# How can update single data object in Hive Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, hive, nosql, flutter-hive

I have entered data in hive database Hive Flutter and I want to update single data, I've tried but it still doesn't work

I've tried this code for insert data to hive

```
var box = Hive.box<DashboardModel>('db_dashboard');
    box.values.isEmpty
        ? box.put(
            'dashboard',
            DashboardModel(
              dayOne: 30,
              dayTwo: 5,
              dayThree: 10,
              dayFour: 7,
              dayFive: 0,
              daySix: 2,
            ),
          )
        : DoNothingAction();
```

how can I update single data in database, ex. I want to update only dayTwo to 40 ?

I tried with the following code but the data other than what I updated turned into null,

```
var boxDashboard = Hive.box<DashboardModel>('db_dashboard');
    boxDashboard.put(
      'dashboard',
      DashboardModel(
        dayTwo: 40,
      ),
    );
```

is it possible hive to be able to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only a single element is not possible and to update model do like this

```
   var boxDashboard = Hive.box<DashboardModel>('db_dashboard');
    boxDashboard.putAt(index, // you item position 
        DashboardModel(
          dayOne: 30,
          dayTwo: 40, // you new parameter remaining data will be same
          dayThree: 10,
          dayFour: 7,
          dayFive: 0,
          daySix: 2,
        ),
);
```